# chutzpah CI build using TFS and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript

Currently I have visual studio set up using chutzpah, nunit and typescript. All tests show in the test explorer and everything works fine. But when submitting in to source control no tests are detected. It works when set tfs, build definition and chutzpah.json to use test.js files but not test.ts files.

Is there an up-to-date instructions to get this working with CI on TFS 2012 and above?

Comment: There are numerous configuration and files required when I got this working last on TFS 2013 on-premise. Have you seen this link - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah.aspx

Comment: i have looked at this but how I have this set up at the moment is that I have chutzpah installed on the build server with visual studio and because of this we didn't need to pass in to source control?